# Removing Query String from ServletRequest after it reaches the Servlet/Filter

Tags: java, servlets, filter, query-string

Now suppose I fire some URL say

```
http://shoaib:8080/userAuthentication?authenticate=false
```

Now when it reaches the doFilter method of Filter

```
public void doFilter(request,response,filterChain){

   boolean authenticate=request.getParameter("authenticate");
   .
   .   //some logic
   .
   .
   filterChain.doFilter(request,response); //this request should not have query String.

}
```

The request which will be pass to `filterChain's doFilter()`  should not have queryString. How I can achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure about this. But would this work ? 
Map params = request.getParameterMap();
params.remove("parameter-to-remove"); `

Comment: I think it would not work as HTTP Status 500 - No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about overriding Filter method:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

    if (requestURI.startsWith(YOUR_CHECK_PATH)) {
       String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
       String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
        req.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(req, res);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't the request still have the query string?

Comment: so now next time if you call request.getQueryString() it should be null. I think this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot, but finally i change the url at the client side using window.location object

**Previous path:**

```
http://shoaib:8080/userAuthentication?authenticate=false
```

**Client side code**

```
window.location.pathname="userAuthentication";
```

This removed the previous Query string

**Current URL**

```
http://shoaib:8080/userAuthentication
```